# Add an Index to a searchBar

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift2, uisearchbar, xcode7

Need help to correct this code. 
 I have a coredata app with restaurant names and address, have a search Bar and it is working. What I want to add is a Index and a IndexTitle as showed in the picture below (arrows). 
Any help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DictionaryTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
{
    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var searchResults:[Dictionary] = []

    private var dictionaryItems:[Dictionary] = []
    var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DictionaryEntity")
            do {
                dictionaryItems = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Dictionary]
            } catch {
                print("Failed to retrieve record")
                print(error)
            }
        }

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

           tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 26
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.active {
            return searchResults.count
        } else {
            return dictionaryItems.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DictionaryTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.wordLabel.text = dictionaryItems[indexPath.row].word
        cell.definitionSmallLabel.text = dictionaryItems[indexPath.row].definition

    let dictionary = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row]: dictionaryItems[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.wordLabel.text = dictionary.word
        cell.definitionSmallLabel.text = dictionary.definition
        return cell
    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? 
    {
        return "dictionaryItems\(section)"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

           if searchController.active{
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDictionaryDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DictionaryDetailViewController
                destinationController.dictionary = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : dictionaryItems[indexPath.row]
                searchController.active = false
            }
        }
    }

        func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:
            UISearchController) {
                if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
                    filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }

        func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
            searchResults = dictionaryItems.filter({ (dictionary:Dictionary) -> Bool in
                let wordMatch = dictionary.word!.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
                    NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
                return wordMatch != nil
            })
        }
}
```

What I am trying to have in my table View is the Index (Arrows in the left) and the Index Title (Arrows in the right side).

[image]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: ERROR: Method does not override any method from its superclass...........................    override func tableview(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "dictionaryItems\(section)"
    }

Comment: You have a typo: the method is `titleForHeaderInSection` (note the **In**).

Comment: @ pbasdf thanks it was my error, but the error is still the same, what I am trying is to have a section and a index with alphabet in the right side, like the  contacts on iphone. I think there is something wrong with the code... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in your override function for *titleForHeaderInSection*

Here is the corrected one, note that **v** in tableView is capital: (copy paste my code)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

}
```

I'd recommend using the auto-complete feature of Xcode. that way, you don't get stuck in insidious errors like this.

**UPDATE**:
You also need to provide both of these methods to see section header and section index titles.

```
override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return ["A", "B", "C"]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "A title for section: \(section)"
}
```

Try the following code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 9
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 9
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section+1)\(indexPath.row+1)"

    return cell
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return ["A", "C", "B"]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "SECTION \(section+1)"
}
```

}

Comment: <BR> Hi I fixed my typos, but still does not show the Index and the IndexTitle. any other tip? :)

Comment: @Jade, you also need to provide **sectionIndexTitlesForTableView** to see indices.

Comment: I also updated my answer with a sample code that demonstrates how it works. I tested that and it works on my iPhone 6 running iOS 9.0. let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: great now I can see the indexTitle and the A-Z Index as well, two problems, IndexTitle show numbers instead of the letters selected in the A-Z Index, it changes for the the Section Title number but instead of showing the words that begin with this letter shows the entire database after every Section Title. What am I doing wrong??? :(

Comment: Ok so a few things: 1. Make sure number of sections matches number of section index titles (on the right side), it works in order so if you provide less, it'll navigate to wrong section. 2. You get the entire database in every section because you provide it yourself; in the function **numberOfRowsInSection**, UITableViewDataSource asks for the number of items for that specific section, it's your job to give it the right number and right table view cell in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: So if you want to do it alphabetically, filter out your array based on the section number in **numberOfRowsInSection**. For example, in section A, return number of items in database who start with letter 'A' instead of returning the length of the entire array.

Comment: that is one big problem the database is huge, I can not count number of each letter, the database is more than 10K rows.

Comment: Well, are you planning on showing the entire 10K rows in the table view? all at the same time? you'd have problem loading that many regardless.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using built-in properties on the NSFetchedResultsController. The most important part of this is setting up the sectionNameKeyPath (which should be the managed object attribute holding the title).

```
private var frc: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
private lazy var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController = {

        if self.frc != nil {
            return self.frc!
        }
        //grab your managed object context
        let moc = dbStore.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext


        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Transaction")
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30
        fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.ManagedObjectResultType
        let sortDescriptorByTimeStamp =  NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorByTimeStamp]

        //in-memory cache when cachename is nil, delegate is non-nil
        //note the sectionNameKeyPath requires that I have a related category object with the categoryName attribute on my Transaction managed object
        let nfrc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "category.categoryName", cacheName: nil)

        self.frc = nfrc
        do
        {
            try self.frc!.performFetch()
        } catch let e as NSError {
            fatalError(e.localizedDescription)
        }

        return self.frc!
    }()
```

### Section Titles

To get the section titles you implement this method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let sectionTitle = self.fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].name ?? "No Category Titles"
        return sectionTitle

}
```

### Table Index

To setup the index you implement the following method.

```
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

        return self.fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles ?? [""]

}
```

> **Note the Quick Help Documentation** when you click on
>   sectionIndexTitles. *The array of section index titles. The default
>   implementation returns the array created by calling
>   sectionIndexTitleForSectionName: on all the known sections. You should
>   override this method if you want to return a different array for the
>   section index. You only need this method if you use a section index.*

### Source

If you want to see this in context, to get the gist of how to use the NSFetchedResultsController in this way you can checkout [my sample at this location](https://gist.github.com/mingsai/64ee12684bc7eaff3a0a).

### Alternates (Arrays/Dictionaries)

There are a few other tutorials about how to build an index from arrays and dictionaries (but I recommend the method above as simplest way to proceed).

- [Alternate Tutorial #1](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing)
- [Alternate Tutorial #2](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

### Alternate Implementation

*Note: Code in this section is from Alternate Tutorial #1*

```
 // `UIKit` convenience class for sectioning a table
    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
        as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
....
/* section headers
       appear above each `UITableView` section */
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
        -> String {
        // do not display empty `Section`s
        if !self.sections[section].users.isEmpty {
            return self.collation.sectionTitles[section] as String
        }
        return ""
    }

    /* section index titles
       displayed to the right of the `UITableView` */
    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView)
        -> [AnyObject] {
        return self.collation.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
        atIndex index: Int)
        -> Int {
        return self.collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
    }
```

Comment: so my code will not work for index, I have to change to yours. I was looking for something to add to this code from appcoda tutorial :(

Comment: @Manolo - Give the NSFRC a try, I think you will find it a cleaner solution. See my source code (link above) for how to handle the typical tableview delegate/datasource methods when using NSFRC. I think that the tutorial is using an older method, NSFRC is much faster, easier to use, and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your time but my knowledge is not enough to make all this changes, I was wondering if someone could help me with this code from the tutorial and show me why I can not make it work.

Comment: @Manolo Did you have a separate question posted somewhere with your code? If you can share that then I can assist in your specific question.

Comment: @Tommie C. I dont have other question but here is the code from the tutorial I am trying to change and learn from... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14313867/CockpitDictionary.zip